# Classic ASP and xsl xsl:for-each setting a from and to value

Tags: xml, xslt, asp-classic, pagination

currently i have the following piece of code that will list the last 12 articles:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item[position() &lt;= 12]">
```

What i would like is similar to a pagination effect. Is there a way to have a between as:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item[position() &gt;= 12 & &lt;= 24]">
```

I would pass in the values like in my asp page:

```
  mm_xsl.addParameter "from",
  mm_xsl.addParameter "to"
```

Then have in my xsl page:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item[position() &gt;= $from & &lt;= $to]">
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You almost have the correct predicate you just need to put the correct syntax in it. You wold update it to the below:

```
<xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item[position() &gt;= $from and position() &lt;= $to]">
```

That would give you all of your items with a position between your two variables.

Comment: Thanks will give it ago in the morning and feed back much appreciated.